# CSS (JQUERY): border around icon

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, icons, border

[image]When large icons are used a border is visible around the icon area.

```
I have tried: 
.ui-icon {
border: none;
}
```

That was not the solution. Any ideas or can you point me in the right direction?

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.ui-icon-green5{
background-image: url(green_05_64x64.png);
}
.ui-icon {
background-color: transparent;
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
border: none;
margin-top:150px;
margin-left:150px;
}

a{
    line-height: 600px; 
 }
-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="content2" style="background-color:#000000;height:400px;width:400px;float:left;">
        <a data-theme="a" id="start-button" data-iconpos="top" data-icon="green5"
          data-role="button"
          href="index.html"
          data-corners="false">LIVINGROOM</a>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: could we see the code? not a lot to go on here.

Comment: Also, are you sure the problem is jQuery and not CSS?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
.ui-icon {
   border: 0 !important;
}
```

if that does not work, the border got to be on the png itself

Comment: I double checked and the border is not on the png

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what causes this problem. I might be worth though to set the outline to none as well, instead of only the border. Some browsers, like chrome, might use this to indicate the focus of an element (though i don't recall seeing it happen on a link, only on input fields). Another thing that might be worth checking is wheter this is not actully an artefact in your image. It might be that you have a fade to white at the edges, are you may have sliced it incorrctly. Putting it over a black background in a Photoshop like programm should show this immediatly.

Also i don't know what all this data attributes are for, suppose they have something to do with some jQuery plugin you use. Anyway, I would set a class of ui-icon to your link to make sure the border: none (and outline: none ) definitly get applied, as from the current snippet i can't say they do.

Comment: I have tried: border: 0 !important;
      outline: none !important;
      border-style: none !important; but the border remains

Answer (score 0):

-webkit-box-shadow: none;

This solves the problem. [image]